# Merging Two Json Files using JQ

Tags: json, jq

I have two json files that I would like to merge using jq in order to pass to AWS Lambda as a payload.

File 1

```
 {
    "Product": {
      "name": "Foo"
      "description": "bar",
     }
}
```

File 2

```
 {
    "Store": {
      "id": "123"
      "location": "abc",
     }
}
```

My desired output:

```
 {
    "Product": {
      "name": "Foo"
      "description": "bar",
     },
    "Store": {
      "id": "123"
      "location": "abc",
     }
}
```

I know I can do `jq -s . File1 File2`, but this puts it into an array - is there a way to do this merge without putting the two files into an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seemed to work `jq -s '.[0] * .[1]' File1 File2`

Comment: The infix `+` operator for objects is probably want you want. Its semantics is quite straightforward.